# how to change zopehome variable

Tags: zope

from App.config import getConfiguration

When I print getConfiguration it shows 
`/home/zeo_zope/zope-2.13.19/lib/python2.6`

I do not understand how it sets the variable to the above value.

How can I change this to /home/zeo_zope ?

Comment: Read the source of App/config.py... set the ZOPE_HOME environment variable.  You have not described why you want to do this, though?

Comment: Thanks for that. I recently installed multiple zeo clients. Hence, need to store all the file uploads on the file system inside a directory outside zeo clients. (please suggest if you can think of a better approach).  I chose to use ZOPE_HOME and expected it to be /home/zeo_zope but it pointed to the path mentioned in the question.